# Add the inline css in Angular 7 from component.ts

Tags: angular

My angular 7 application, I have the scrolling to see the products from left to right and right to left using this.
**Scrolling**

Each image has the button when ever it is clicked, I have applied the new CSS in typescript (component.ts) as below.

```
this.appendToSimilar.nativeElement.appendChild(document.getElementById(item.imageId).cloneNode()).classList.add('similar-floating');
```

Here, I need to pass the inline css instead of class name.

**Expectation**

```
this.appendToSimilar.nativeElement.appendChild(document.getElementById(item.imageId).cloneNode()).classList.add('.cssClassName{width:50px, hight: 100px}');
```

I am sure that .add can be used to add the class name. Anyone help me to add the inline css for above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

What about using ngStyle

```
customeStyle = 
{
  'color': 'red'
}
```

;

```
  <p [ngStyle]="customeStyle">asdasd</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying the DOM, you can use [Angular Style binding](https://houssein.me/event-and-style-binding-in-angular2)

**Template**

```
<h1 [style.color]="isHoussein() ? 'red': 'black'">{{firstname}}</h1>
Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstname">
<button (click)="changeName()">Change Name</button>
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class MyApp {
  firstname: string = 'Jimmy';

  changeName() {
    this.firstname = 'Houssein';
  }

  isHoussein() {
    return this.firstname === 'Houssein';
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to pass the inline css from component instead of the passing class 

this.appendToSimilar.nativeElement.appendChild(document.getElementById(item.imageId).cloneNode()).classList.add('similar-floating');

Comment: `ngStyle` is an attribute directive that updates styles inline only.

Answer (score 0):

Inject [`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2), and [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) in your component, and add the class by using the renderer, and the nativeElement of elementRef (if you want to do something on the dom-element on your component)

```
constructor(renderer: Renderer2, elementRef: ElementRef) {
    // TODO, create, clone or add classes to the element, or some other element.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add inline css from component.ts in this way:

```
this.appendToSimilar.nativeElement.appendChild(document.getElementById(item.imageId).cloneNode()).style.width = '50px';


this.appendToSimilar.nativeElement.appendChild(document.getElementById(item.imageId).cloneNode()).style.height = '100px';
```